# How to linearize an if-then statement?

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I want to write constraints for finding a path for some rider, driver on a directed network problem.

Let $x_{i,j}^d$ indicate whether driver travels from $i$ to $j$ and $z_{i,j}^{r,d}$ indicates whether riders travel from $i$ to $j$ with driver, and finally, let $y_{i}^{r,d}$ indicate whether driver picks up at $i$ the rider.

I want to ensure that if a driver wants to pick up someone at $i$, then they should travel on an edge connected to $i$. Is this way of writing correct?

$$ y_{i}^{r,d} = 1 \implies \sum_{j: (i,j) \in links} x_{i,j}^d =1$$

Then how to linearize this? Is this even correct?

$$ y_{i}^{r,d} \le  \sum_{j: (i,j) \in links} x_{i,j}^d $$

And, more generally, is there any good resource that explains these linearization techniques very easily and comprehensively? I've searched and everywhere is not complete and easy to understand.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76549/53274) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72592/53274)

Comment: If you are using binary variables, you should mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linear constraint enforces
$$y_{i}^{r,d} = 1 \implies \sum_{j: (i,j) \in links} x_{i,j}^d \ge 1$$
Do you already have other constraints
$$\sum_{j: (i,j) \in links} x_{i,j}^d \le 1?$$
If so, then your proposed linearization is sufficient.

For many linearization examples and links to references, see the [[linearization] tag on the Operations Research StackExchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linearization).

Comment: thanks, I want  to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ in the objective function, do I still need to include $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \le 1$? Is it a must constraints?

Comment: If the $\le 1$ constraint will naturally be satisfied because of the objective, you do not need to explicitly impose it, but doing so might still reduce the solve time.